# How do I display a MaterialAlertDialog?

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog, material-components

I'm changing my app's theme from `AppCompat` to `MaterialComponents` and everything except for the alert dialogues is working. I've already set the app theme to `MaterialComponents` both in styles and in the manifest.

**styles**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/red</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"/>
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"/>
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

This is the code I'm trying to display my dialogue with:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle(R.string.tip_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.tip)
            .setNeutralButton(R.string.ok, null)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.do_not_show_again) { _, _ ->
                preferencesHelper.disableTip()
            }.show()
```

And finally, the error I'm getting is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Which version of material components are you using?

Comment: 1.1.0. Just included it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that displayed the dialogue was taking `Context` as its input parameter, which in turn was the application context injected to the class where the function is.

I managed to fix the issue by changing the input parameter type in the function to `Activity`, which is a way to enforce the right theme.